# Swapping domain name with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to migrate a website to another domain and hope to have requests on the old domain redirected to the new domain, no matter what they are, and regardless of how the URL is structured.

The code below in my .htaccess file does this for a domain and any directories/pages but does not cover the many subdomains I have.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !domain1.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain2.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

How can I add to this in order to convert the following (for example):

http://something.domain1.com/directory/page.php?variable=something
http://something.domain2.com/directory/page.php?variable=something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain2\.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.domain2\.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the help. It seems obvious now.

Comment: Just a note for anyone else who s struggling with this, if you have sub-subdomains, i.e http://sub.sub.domain.com, the above code wont match it all properly. You have to replace ^([^.]+) with ^(.+?) to account for those.